# RealmSwift : libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException

Tags: ios, realm

I was able to save beforehand but I wanted to save async-ly .

User is a class/object.  Whenever I try to run it within a ".async" thread it fails with error :

`libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException`

on line:

`let userObjects = self.realm.objects(User.self)`

Code:

```
  let user = User(dictionary: element as? [String : Any])

                print("entering dispatchqueue realm")
                DispatchQueue(label: "background").async {
                    autoreleasepool {
                        let userObjects = self.realm.objects(User.self)
                        do {
                            try! self.realm.write {
                                self.realm.add(user!, update: true)
                            }
                        }
                        catch {
                            print("error saving to realm")
                            // Handle the error case
                        }

                    }
                }
```

Is it threadsafe?

Edit:

*I was able to get it to work by moving `let realm = try! Realm()` inside the async block*

Comment: did you find a solution for it ?

Answer (score 0):

move `let realm = try! Realm()` inside the async() block.

let user = User(dictionary: element as? [String : Any])

```
            print("entering dispatchqueue realm")
            DispatchQueue(label: "background").async {
                **let realm = try! Realm()**
                autoreleasepool {
                    let userObjects = self.realm.objects(User.self)
                    do {
                        try! self.realm.write {
                            self.realm.add(user!, update: true)
                        }
                    }
                    catch {
                        print("error saving to realm")
                        // Handle the error case
                    }

                }
            }
```